# Tabs for DispForm and Edit Form SP 2010

Tags: javascript

There are tons of jquery tab solutions for page web parts. I can't find anything for custom list DispForm and EditForms for SP 2010? Essentially, I have a custom list with 94 custom fields. That's a LONG display and edit form.

What is the optimal way to apply jQuery Tabs for SP edit and display forms? My last resort would be creating content type for each group of fields, but the UI doesn't look good visually appealing. A company called Kaldeera has a server add-on to process tabs visually, but at $1800 it's expensive.

Any advice? It doesn't have to be jQuery though.

Answer (score 1):

Marc Anderson shows in [this post](http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/18/taming-long-sharepoint-list-forms-using-jquery-to-break-them-into-sections/) how to use the jQuery Accordian function to break long forms up into easier to manage blocks.  You could use the principles there and use tabs from [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) if you want.  I think the accordian effect works well in that scenario too if you aren't hardfast set on using tabs.

Comment: Is it possible to tab content types?

Comment: How so? Anything should be possible, it would just depend on the markup being emitted.

Comment: Tabbing Content Types? Like Eric says, whatever you want to do is possible; you just have to write the script. Keep in mind that you can rearrange the columns on page load totally with script, if that's what you want to do.